# Showing JSON results on front-end when using fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

So really new to React here, and I want to make a simple search box, where the user submits a "question" and the JSON returns the values of "results".

I have a JSON with the structure of two Objects:

```
{
  "request": {
    "date_from": "", 
    "date_to": "", 
    "question": "User question here", 
    "section": null
  }, 
  "results": {
    "docs": [
      {
      "title": " "
      "section": " "

etc..
      ...
```

The request goes through and I get a response, only thing I can't find is taking the results from it and displaying them on the front end.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    searchValue: "",
    searchSection: "",
    results: [],
    // section: []
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSearch = () => {
    this.makeApiCall(this.state.searchValue);
  };

  makeApiCall() {
    fetch("http://myapi.com", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          question: (this.state.searchValue),
          section: (this.state.searchSection),
      })
  })

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(
            "POST Response",
            "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
          )
      })
      .then(results => this.setState({results: results.value}))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main" className="py-16">
        <label className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
            Ask a question
        </label>
        <input
          name="text"
          type="text"
          placeholder=""
          onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
          value={this.state.searchValue}
          className="shadow-sm appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch} className="cursor-pointer mt-5 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded-full shadow">Search</button>

      //THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK NOW
        {this.state.results ? (
          <div id="meals-container">
            {this.state.results.map((result) => (
              <div className="result">
                <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                <p>{result.sentences}</p>
              </div>
            ))}

          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>Can't find results for your question</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

I get

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): results is undefined
```

Comment: You are not returning the result here: `.then((responseData) => {` so in the next `.then` result is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function where responseData is received, you are not returning anything from the function, thus 'undefined' is being set into state.  To fix this you can put a return statement after your console.log:

```
.then((responseData) => {
          console.log(
            "POST Response",
            "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
          )
          return responseData
      })
      .then(results => this.setState({results: results.value}))
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for that. I still don't get results showed to the user though.. I always get the `<p>Can't find results for your question</p>`despite getting a response from the JSON. Something I don't get is wrong after `{this.state.results ? (`

Comment: Anyone? @rob-brander